# Rendering error with a list on IE8, 7, 6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-lists

What is the trick to getting IE to display a `<ul>`? I am working on a page with a `php` extension. I have a simple list.

```
<ul>
    <li>Stuff one</li>
    <li>Stuff two</li>
    <li>Stuff three</li>
    <li>Stuff four</li>
</ul>
```

While on Safari and Firefox I get a list that renders properly, on IE it just displays a paragraph. I have not found one consistant answer on any websites about what could be the problem.

What's happening?

The template is from `Matthew James Taylor's 3 column blog` style layout. 
http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column-blog-style.htm

The css is right in the page. Even when I go back and strip the site to bare bones the lists do not display.

Is there the possibility of screwing up the css because of a div style?

Comment: Nice, professional way of framing the question.  Would you phrase it that way in your office?

Comment: His profile says he is 37 years old, but this question sounds like its from a 16 year old.

Comment: @Tom: do you have any CSS rules affecting `ul` or `li` elements?  If so, please post them.

Comment: Give the guy a break; Maybe he's frustrated with a bug for quite some time; maybe he's under pressure. Also I doubt Tom is 16; I have yet to meet a 16yo man who uses the word consistent - my 2c.

Comment: I apologize for the way I put question. It just seems that if I ever run into a problem with a page, program, or computer they all have one thing in common... windows. Completely frustrating. I will look to the css for the answers. Is there anything specific that I could look for?

Comment: @Tom: See the links in my answer.  I think you have to make sure that if you set a `ul`'s `margin` or `margin-left`, you have to set its `padding` or `padding-left` or the bullets can hang outside of the ul (which might hide them if they are on the left side of the page)

Comment: Having seen the edit history I gotta say there's some serious overreaction to a guy venting some mild frustration (not that this forgives the weakness of the question).

Comment: Somebody flagged this as offensive because of the word "crap"? What kind of farging icehole would do something like that?

Answer (score 6):

IE 6,7,8 should all display unordered lists just fine...

My guess is you have something going on with CSS and/or JS that's causing the list not to be shown in IE.

Comment: Almost definitely the problem - remove the CSS/JS on the page and adding it back in until it breaks if you have to.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the code, you should get a list of four items in all browsers (and all versions).

Check your code for conditional (MS specific) comments such as:

```
<!--IE > Hidden code, could be some CSS <![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

That works fine in IE 6, do have you any css applied to the list?

Answer (score 0):

No, IE does not display `<ul>`'s as paragraphs.  Something else is wrong.  Is it possible that IE-specific css is altering the appearance?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your CSS rules aren't complete.  IE and Opera have a different interpretation of default list styles than other browsers, regarding whether the indentation is done with margins or padding.  If you aren't applying the styles correctly, you can end up with a list that looks wrong on the browser you aren't testing on.  Here is an article that goes into great detail on the differences between the browsers:

[A List Apart: Articles: CSS Design: Taming Lists](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/taminglists/)

**Edit**: And this one:

[Consistent List Indentation](http://devedge-temp.mozilla.org/viewsource/2002/list-indent/)